# Using :inner_lateral in Ecto Elixir

Tags: elixir, ecto

I was trying to use ecto's `:inner_lateral` And I wrote this query

```
SnapshotExtractor
|> order_by(desc: :created_at)
|> limit(1)
|> join(:inner_lateral, [se], cam in fragment("SELECT * FROM cameras as cam WHERE cam.id = ?", se.camera_id))
|> select([se, cam], { se.from_date, se.to_date, se.interval, se.schedule, cam.exid, cam.timezone})
|> Repo.one
```

Its working fine and giving me good resuls but its giving me an un-named object, no name with the resulting values.. Question is can we add names to the values as well? my resulting values are

```
{#Ecto.DateTime<2016-02-25 00:00:00>, #Ecto.DateTime<2016-02-25 00:00:00>, 0,
 %{"Friday" => [], "Monday" => ["0:0-0:0"], "Saturday" => [], "Sunday" => [],
   "Thursday" => [], "Tuesday" => [], "Wednesday" => []}, "oscar2", nil}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you're referring to as "unnamed object" is a tuple. You're getting that back because your `select` expression is a tuple. You probably want a Map if you want to give them names. To get back a Map, just return a Map in the `select` expression:

```
|> select([se, cam], %{ from_date: se.from_date, to_date: se.to_date, interval: se.interval, schedule: se.schedule, exid: cam.exid, timezone: cam.timezone})
```

If you assign the return value to `foo`, you can access the fields using `foo.from_date`, `foo.to_date`, etc.

Comment: Thanks.. I wasnt aware of this! after 7 minutes.. I will accept the answer.